# Why bother calculating the inverse of 3 by 3 matrix?

Tags: inverse

My government has told me that I must teach 17 year olds how to invert a 3 by 3 matrix using adjoints/cofactors, without using any technology.

1. Is there any reason why you would want to know how to do this by hand? (As opposed to on calculator)
2. When we went through the step-by-step recipe ("And now, you change the signs of these entries...") the students wanted to know **why** it works. I am loath to hand over a magic recipe without justifying, but am unsure of what to say. What could I say?

Comment: See [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) (video 8 is about inverses) for some inspitration on explaining why the calculations are the way they are. As for why they should learn it? They shouldn't. Almost no concrete piece of math they learn at that stage is something they should learn (unless they want a career in something mathematical). That being said, learning new mathematics _is_ important for their logical sense, and linear algebra is as good a field as any.

Comment: Why don't you ask your government instead? IMHO using adjoints/cofactors is a bad idea. The fact that you can't tell them why it works is one clue that it's a bad idea. Another clue is that it's more complex than Gauss elimination in most cases.

Comment: Also, a focus on calculation algorithms in education is a bad thing in my opinion. They need to know some step-by-step recipes, but too many of them and too much time spent practicing them is both boring and not what mathematics is about.

Comment: If no one bothered finding ways to do it then numerical linear algebra would be much more unexplored than it is. Which would be a shame, because it is really useful all over science and engineering.

Comment: Vote to replace your government.

Comment: Thank you. I will ask the British government. Thanks for the 3Blue1Brown link Arthur - beautiful animations.

Comment: For 2x2 it makes sense, for 3x3 it is unmotivated busy-work (although math majors will eventually need to be able to understand the mathematics behind such things).

Comment: If the topic inspires students asking “why,” then the topic is worthy of being presented.

Comment: I'll dare say it's because it is "easy" to do. Easy in the sense that it requires almost no thinking once you've done enough.

Eliminating most of the computational side of math in favor of deeper understanding is a good idea in practice, but students have a harder time with that. They feel in control when they do algorithmic computations because it's what they've always done in maths.

The whole curriculum would need to be redesigned. I don't know how though, I wish I did.

Answer (score 3):

In computer graphics, the *view matrix* is the inverse of the *camera matrix*.
This is needed, e.g., in [game programming](https://www.3dgep.com/understanding-the-view-matrix/).

In general, matrices are used to convert from coordinate system A to coordinate system B, and the inverse converts in the opposite direction, from B to A. [There are circumstances where both are needed](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/43930/13295).

---

[image: ProjMat]

          

<sup>(Image from UC Santa Barbara, CS180 Intro Comp Graphics.)</sup>

---

Generally the matrices used in computer graphics are $4 \times 4$—homogenous coordinates. But that is a minor difference.

So this motivates the need for the inverse ("Why bother calculating the inverse ..."?). You could not program this without knowing how to do it "by hand" (1). So a motivation for understanding it at that level is that detailed knowledge is needed to actually implement the inverse. A motivation for understanding the concept is that one cannot become a game programmer without understanding matrix inverses.

Answer (score 0):

It shows why every matrix with non-zero determinant has an inverse, and vice-versa, every invertible matrix has non-zero determinant.  So there is a quick calculation to decide whether three simultaneous equations have a unique solution.